# ¿Como insertar varias imágenes con PHP y MySql?

Tags: php, html, mysql, imagen

Realizo un formulario el cual necesito insertar varias imágenes (5 imágenes) que son relacionadas con un producto. 
En mi base de datos inserta el nombre de la imagen y después la redirige a una carpeta en especifico, utilizo la el atributo "multiple" para que en mi formulario me deje elegir varias imágenes pero solo sube una a mi sistema, lo que pretendo que en mi campo Imagen en mi BD se inserten los nombres de todas la imágenes.

**Código Input**

```
 <div class="form-group">
 <label>IMAGEN</label>
 <input type="file" name="img[]" multiple="multiple">
 <p class="help-block">Formato de imagenes admitido png, jpg, gif, jpeg</p>
  </div>
```

**Código PHP**

```html
  if(!$codeProd=="" && !$nameProd=="" && !$cateProd=="" && !$priceProd=="" && !$medProd=="" && !$tecProd=="" && !$oriProd=="" && !$acercaProd=="" && !$stockProd=="" && !$codePProd=="" && !$_FILES['img']['name']==""){
        $verificar=  ejecutarSQL::consultar("select * from producto where CodigoProd='".$codeProd."'");
        $verificaltotal = mysql_num_rows($verificar);
        if($verificaltotal<=0){
            if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['img']['tmp_name'],"../assets/img-products/".$_FILES['img']['name'])){
                if(consultasSQL::InsertSQL("producto", "CodigoProd, NombreProd, CodigoCat, Precio, Medidas, CodigoTec, CodigoOri, Acerca, Stock, NITProveedor, Imagen, Nombre", "'$codeProd','$nameProd','$cateProd','$priceProd', '$medProd','$tecProd', '$oriProd', '$acercaProd','$stockProd','$codePProd','".$_FILES['img']['name']."','$adminProd'")){
                   echo '
                        <img src="../assets/img/correctofull.png" class="center-all-contens">
                        <br>
                        <h3>El producto se añadio a la tienda con éxito</h3>
                        <p class="lead text-cente">
                            La pagina se redireccionara automaticamente. Si no es asi haga click en el siguiente boton.<br>
                            <a href="../configAdmin.php" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Volver a administración</a>
                        </p>';
               }

 ?>
```

De antemano muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Recuerda que estas enviando un array de archivos con la opción multiple, y por lo tanto tienes que recorrer cada elemento del array en php para poder mover cada uno de esos elementos al servidor, y también guardar cada uno de esos nombres en tu tabla. 
Entonces, para mover todas tus imágenes al servidor, necesitas usar un 'foreach', de la siguiente manera:

```
foreach($_FILES['img']['tmp_name'] as $clave => $tmp_name){
    $nombre_original_imagen = $_FILES['img']['name'][$clave]; 
    $recurso = $_FILES["img"]["tmp_name"][$clave];

    if(move_upload_file($recurso, "../assets/img-products/".$nombre_original_name)){
        //código
    }

}
```

Luego, en cada iteracción del foreach puedes agregar el nombre del archivo en un array y ese array de nombres de imágenes guardarlo en la DB.

Comment: Bunas noches Diego gracias por responder, trate de implementar tu código pero me arroja el siguiente error: Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()